# How to concate two pointer character?

Tags: c++, c++11

I am building a fast copy application using xcopy. I want to pass two variable source and destination to system(); I am trying like this

```
char *source = "D:\\SOFTWARE\\Internet";
char *destination = " D:\\test /s /e /d /y";

system("xcopy "+source+destination);
```

But it doesnt work. It work fine in java. same code. Thanks.

Comment: That won't work. One option for C-strings is `char cmd[1024]; snprintf(cmd, sizeof cmd, "%s%s", source, destination); system(cmd);`.

Comment: Use `std::string` instead of C-style `char` pointers. Also beware that your arguments are unquoted and may be misinterpreted by your shell.

Comment: Code doesnt work for me.

Answer (score 1):

Rewriting Mike's code to eliminate all the issues we tend to flag in code being reviewed!

```
#include <string>
#include <cstdlib>

using std::string;

int main()
{
    const string str{ "dir" };
    const string str2{ " /w" };

    const string  final_string = str + str2;

    std::system(final_string.c_str()); 
}
```

Your problem in your original code is that `operator+` doesn't work with C style strings, which are just `char*` or `char[]` and not objects.  You are asking to add pointers together, which is not a sensible thing.

As Mike points out, turn your raw char array input into `std::string` objects as soon as you need to do stuff with it, and then `+` will work.

In this particular case, you only need to copy one of the character arrays into objects (see docs on [operator+=](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/operator%2B%3) form 3):

```
string s {"xcopy "};
s += source;
s += destination;  // this works, as there is an optimized form of operator+ for this.
std::system(s.c_str());  // access a nul-terminated character array to make the system call.
```

Answer (score 0):

One more way of string concatenation is use of [`std::ostringstream`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostringstream). Source and destination paths are quoted in the code bellow to be more safe:

```
#include <sstream>

int main() {
    const char *source = "\"D:\\SOFTWARE\\Internet\"";
    const char *destination = " \"D:\\test\" /s /e /d /y";
    
    std::ostringstream cmd;
    cmd << "xcopy " << source << destination;
    
    system(cmd.str().c_str());
}
```

[Compile and run](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/c4554c93fb1d2e1e)

Answer (score -3):

You need to use *std::string* (from string header).  Also, you need to go from string to a const char pointer.

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_DEPRECATE

#include <cstdlib>
#include <string>

int main()
{
    using namespace std;
    string str{ "dir" };
    string str2{ " /w" };
    string  final_string = str + str2;

    char* cstr = new char[final_string.size() + 1];
    strcpy(cstr, final_string.c_str());
    system(cstr); 
}
```

Comment: give an error: no matching function for call to system

Comment: don't write `using namespace std;`.  Use `const` in a lot of places.  Don't use naked `new`.  You don't need to copy out the string contents in order to use `system` rather just use `final_string.c_str()`.

Comment: @coder_haslib The #include file `<cstdlib>` brings in the names inside the `std` namespace and *might* or *might not* also have them as global names.

Comment: Screwed the pooch on this one.  Thanks for the corrections @JDługosz.